# pass urls to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application with a lots of jQuery ajax calls (usually to refresh lists etc.). I'm using $.load mostly. The rebinding/action js scripts are naturally in Scripts folders in .js files. At this moment I'm holding all links in _Layout.cshtml like this

```
    var GET_ARTICLE_LIST = '@Url.Action("List","Article",null)';
    var GET_FILES_LIST = '@Url.Action("Files","Library", null)';
```

then I'm using it in a code like this

```
    $('.element').load(GET_ARTICLE_LIST);
```

is there any nicer way to pass ASP.NET MVC @Url.Action link to .js files?

Comment: try doing a console on that like `console.log(GET_ARTICLE_LIST )` and see what's coming there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the url in a data-attribute of the element that triggers the ajax call (i.e. a button or link etc)

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" data-url="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" />

var url = $(your_element).data('url');
$('.element').load(url);
```

Comment: well, I guess it's the cleanest solution

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to make a javascript function in the Layout that returns you the url? 
For example:

```
function GetUrl(controller, action){
    return '@Url.Action("ACTION", "CONTROLLER")'.replace('ACTION',action).replace('CONTROLLER',controller);
}
```

so you don't have to write all this urls.

Comment: @Url.Action executes on server so this will execute Url.Action("ACTION", "CONTROLLER") long before the js executes, which will most likely yield an error

Comment: Yes it does execute on the server. Thats why we have the replace statements after that.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the result of the call to @Url.Action will contain substrings "ACTION" and/or "CONTROLLER", this depends on how you have set up your routes.

Comment: There isn't any call here. You are just generating the url string. So if you are developing on localhost you will have the GetUrl function look like :

function GetUrl(controller, action){
    return 'localhost/CONTROLLER/ACTION'.replace('CONTROLLER',controller).replace('ACTION',action);
}
and when ever you call with with your parameters you will get the needed url